# React - tabela dinâmica - Adicionando e removendo linhas da tabela

Tags: react, typescript

Escrevi o seguinte código abaixo, ele está 100% funcional com uma exceção.

Ao clicar em "remover" referente a linha desejada, ele remove a última linha, e não a correta (ou seja, adiciono 5 linhas, solicito q remova a segunda, e na verdade ele remove a última).

Curioso que no array ele remove corretamente, o problema está apenas na view.

O código está bem simples e funcional, copiando e compilando em qualquer lugar deve funcionar bem.

Podem me ajudar com esse último item faltante (referente a remover a linha correta - de preferencia usando typescript)? Obrigado.

```
import React, { useState } from 'react';

export default function Test() {  
    const [infos, setInfos] = useState([
        { 'info1': '', 'info2': '', 'info3': '' }
    ]);
    
    function addNewInfoItem() {
        setInfos([
            ...infos,
            { 'info1': '', 'info2': '', 'info3': '' }
        ]);
    };

    function removeInfoItem(index: any) {
        const itensCopy = Array.from(infos);
        itensCopy.splice(index, 1);
        setInfos(itensCopy);
    };

    function updateInfosItem(position:number, field:string, item:string) {
    const updatedInfoItems = infos.map((standardItem, index) => {
        if (index === position) {
            return { ...standardItem, [field]: item }
        }
        return standardItem
    })
    setInfos(updatedInfoItems)
  }

  return (
    <div>
        {infos.map((item, index) => {
            return (
                <div key={index}>
                    <button onClick={e => removeInfoItem(index)}> Remover </button>
                    <input
                        required
                        type="text"
                        onChange={e => updateInfosItem(index, 'info1', e.target.value)}
                    />
                    <input
                        required
                        type="text"
                        onChange={e => updateInfosItem(index, 'info2', e.target.value)}
                    />
                    <input
                        required
                        type="text"
                        onChange={e => updateInfosItem(index, 'info3', e.target.value)}
                    />
                </div>
            );
        })}
        <pre> {JSON.stringify(infos, null, 4)} </pre>
        <button onClick={addNewInfoItem}> Adicionar </button> 
    </div>
  );
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Basicamente, o que aconteceu para seu código está apresentando um comportamento estranho, é o fato de você não ter definido um valor padrão para esses inputs. Até porque, como você falou, é removido corretamente do `array` do `state`, então o problema não está na lógica em si, mas na hora de exibir os dados.

Para resolver isso, basta adicionar um `value={infos[index].info<equi>}` equivalente em cada um dos inputs, ou seja:

- `value={infos[index].info1}` no primeiro input;
- `value={infos[index].info2}` no segundo input;

e assim por diante...

Ficaria assim:

```js
function App() {
  const [infos, setInfos] = React.useState([{ info1: '', info2: '', info3: '' }]);
  
  
  function addNewInfoItem() {
    setInfos([...infos, { info1: '', info2: '', info3: '' }]);
  }

  function removeInfoItem(index: any) {
    const itensCopy = Array.from(infos);

    itensCopy.splice(index, 1);

    setInfos(itensCopy);
  }

  function updateInfosItem(position: number, field: string, item: string) {
    const updatedInfoItems = infos.map((standardItem, index) => {
      if (index === position) {
        return { ...standardItem, [field]: item };
      }

      return standardItem;
    });

    setInfos(updatedInfoItems);
  }

  return (
    <div>
      {infos.map((item, index) => {
        return (
          <div key={index}>
            <button onClick={(e) => removeInfoItem(index)}> Remover </button>
            <input
              required
              type="text"
              onChange={(e) => updateInfosItem(index, 'info1', e.target.value)}
              value={infos[index].info1}
            />
            <input
              required
              type="text"
              onChange={(e) => updateInfosItem(index, 'info2', e.target.value)}
              value={infos[index].info2}
            />
            <input
              required
              type="text"
              onChange={(e) => updateInfosItem(index, 'info3', e.target.value)}
              value={infos[index].info3}
            />
          </div>
        );
      })}
      <pre> {JSON.stringify(infos, null, 4)} </pre>
      <button onClick={addNewInfoItem}> Adicionar </button>
    </div>
  );
}

ReactDOM.render( < App / > , document.getElementById("root"));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.13.1/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.13.1/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
<div id="root"></div>
```

Faça os testes e veja se resolveu seu problema.